# How can I close an SSL connection in an ASP.NET page

Tags: asp.net, ssl

I found a lot of information about creating ssl connections, but not closing them.  (At least, not easily.)

Users login to private pages on the web site through a sign in page using SSL. For example, https://example.com/signin.aspx.

All private pages have a logout link that simply navigates to the public home page using http://example.com in the url.

Unfortunately, they can then hit the back button on the browser to navigate back to the protected page, and of course the connection is still live.

Is there a simple way to close this connection so that it cannot be reopened without the user logging in?

Answer (score 1):

Normally back button doesn't create a new request to server. Instead, it displays the content cached by browser.

You can try adding this to page to prevent browser caching.

```
// Prevent caching of this page.
Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(-1));
Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
Response.Cache.SetNoStore();
```

[A Thorough Examination of "Disabling the Back Button."](https://web.archive.org/web/20210927201700/http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/webtech/111500-1.shtml)